# How to solve this problemm? SVN 1.8.19: E170000: Unrecognized URL scheme

Tags: python, linux, svn

I want to use svn on my linux server(SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11), and I install the svn 1.8.19, But when I use: svn update, problem shows up:

```
   svn: E170000: Unrecognized URL scheme for 'http://.....'
```

These are infomation for svn:

```
svn, version 1.8.19 (r1800620)
compiled Aug 31 2017, 16:07:39 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

Copyright (C) 2017 The Apache Software Foundation.
This software consists of contributions made by many people;
see the NOTICE file for more information.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.apache.org/
```

The following repository access (RA) modules are available:

```
* ra_svn : Module for accessing a repository using the svn network protocol.
  - handles 'svn' scheme
* ra_local : Module for accessing a repository on local disk.
  - handles 'file' scheme
```

And then I find out that I need to install scons-2.5.1 and serf-1.3.9, but After I install the scons-2.5.1 , I got an error:

```
SCons import failed. Unable to find engine files in:
 /usr/local/bin/../engine
 /usr/local/bin/scons-local-2.5.1
 /usr/local/bin/scons-local
 /usr/local/lib/scons-2.5.1
 /usr/lib/scons-2.5.1
 /usr/local/lib/scons-2.5.1
 /usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scons-2.5.1
 /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scons-2.5.1
 /usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scons-2.5.1
 /usr/lib64/scons-2.5.1
 /usr/local/lib/scons
 /usr/lib/scons
 /usr/local/lib/scons
 /usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scons
 /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scons
 /usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scons
 /usr/lib64/scons
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/bin/scons", line 190, in <module>
 import SCons.Script
 ImportError: No module named SCons.Script
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `svn` client was not build with support for http and https. It is missing `serf` (`libserf`) library that adds http and https support.

Comment: That means I should install serf first? But I can't install the scons,( compile serf need the  scons ) ...