# How to properly configure `serf` during Subversion compilation?

Tags: linux, svn

First of all, I'm aware of [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/522806/488948), yet as it's quite vague, it didn't help me solve my problem.

I'm working on CentOS machine and as [current subversion package is quite old](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-aarch64/subversion-1.7.14-16.el7.aarch64.rpm.html), I needed to compile svn by myself. I've managed to do that, but trying to use one of commands I need, which is:

```
$ svnsync initialize [...] [...]
```

Resulted with the following error:

> svnsync: E170000: Unrecognized URL scheme for '[url here]'

After some research, I found that I [need](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/INSTALL) [serf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46012459/how-to-solve-this-problemm-svn-1-8-19-e170000-unrecognized-url-scheme) to make it work, so I've installed it by using `yum install libserf` (I'm not sure if it's it, but name and description sound similar to what I need). Unfortunately, nothing has changed and I later came to a conclusion that maybe I need to recompile svn with serf in place.

I've downloaded subversion source and ran `./configure`. Here is the output of it associated with `serf`:

```
configure: serf library configuration via pkg-config
checking for serf-2 library... no
checking for serf-1 library... no
checking was serf enabled... no

An appropriate version of serf could not be found, so libsvn_ra_serf
will not be built.  If you want to build libsvn_ra_serf, please
install serf 1.3.4 or newer.
```

There is an argument called `--with-serf`, but I'm not sure how should I use it. Linking to location of `serf` binaries, like that:

```
$ ./configure --with-serf=/usr/lib64/
```

results with the following output:

```
configure: serf library configuration via pkg-config
checking for serf-2 library... no
checking for serf-1 library... no
checking was serf enabled... no

An appropriate version of serf could not be found, so libsvn_ra_serf
will not be built.  If you want to build libsvn_ra_serf, please
install serf 1.3.4 or newer.

configure: error: Serf was explicitly enabled but an appropriate version was not found.
```

Can you give me some hints on how can I proceed with this?

Comment: I'm having the same issue here.  It seems like the configure script is completely broken?   It pings `pkg-config` for "serf-1" and "serf-2", but serf actually appears in pkg-config as just "serf".   And passing the explicit path doesn't work either, for similar reasons.